# Dividing polygon with another polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, polygon, modelbuilder

I am working in ArcMap 10.1 or any upto v10.8

I am trying to divide a polygon with another polygon. I don´t want to clip any part away, but only to divide the polygon?
//Edit:-For example: I have a polygon(watershed) containing 15 LULC classes(say1,2,3...15) and I have to divide each classes based on another polygon(hydrologic soil groups of the same watershed) which contain three soil groups(say A,B,C). Hence the new polygon has an attribute table which contains features 1A, 1B,1C,2A,2B,2C...15A,15B,15C)//

I would like to do it using the ModelBuilder tool.

I have tried the split function but it is not working.
In this tool I have to choose an input and a field that the division is based on, but none of the fields are working.

Comment: what about identity tool ?

Comment: Would you be able to include some pictures of sample input polygons and the desired output polygons, please?

Answer (score 1):

you can also use split tool .
Splitting the Input Features creates a subset of multiple output feature classes.
The Split Field's unique values form the names of the output feature classes. These are saved in the target workspace.

see this link : [Split tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000006000000)

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the polygon that you want to be split:

> Click Split Polygons Split Polygons on the Advanced Editing toolbar.
>   Click the layer in which to store the new features. When splitting
>   features this way, you choose the layer in which to store the new
>   feature. This allows you to retain the attribute values from the
>   existing feature, rather than having them be overwritten with values
>   from a feature template. Optionally, type a cluster tolerance. You
>   should use the default cluster tolerance or match the cluster
>   tolerance of the geodatabase topology, if you are using one. Click OK.

Note: Setup your snapping (snap to the no editing polygon edge) so that split is exact.

Full documentation:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m600000045000000